# migrar codigo php a asp classic

Tags: php, asp

necesito migrar el php de un envio de mail a asp classic y voy bastante perdido.
El codigo es simple pero ya lo intente y la conversion no consigo realizarla

código del php

```
error_reporting(0); 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
$correo_electronico= $_POST['email']; 
$mensaje=$_POST['message']; 
$mail= $_POST['email']; 
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n"; 
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain"; 
$add_header = "From: xxx@xxx.com \r\n"; 
//$add_header = "From: xxx@xxx.com <".$_POST[nombre].">\r\n"; 
$para = 'yyy@yyy.com'; 
$asunto = 'mensaje(xxx.com)'; 
mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $add_header); 
echo "Su mensaje ha sido enviado.";
```

Comment: Yo lo enfocaría de una manera diferente. No trates de convertir el código de php a asp, sino mas bien busca _enviar email con asp_ en google, estoy seguro de que encontrarás varios ejemplos.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código que intentaste y qué errores/fallos te dieron.